# Two projects in one solution

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I have two projects in my Visual Studio solution. One is an empty WEB API application with AngularJS and html front-end. Other is WEB API project with embedded database, controllers and stuff. The problem is when I call web api controllers from my first solution, I'm getting 404 not found. I suspect there is a problem in a hosting, but I don't know what kind exactly. I tried to host back-end project in IIS, but no results. Maybe there is something I missed.

Comment: why do you need two separated solutions? wouldn't be easier to put everything in one?

Comment: I have one solution with two projects in it

Comment: Is the Global.ascx or startup class has the routes added !! Can you show the code in that please.

Comment: @satish, I pasted code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot time spent on investigating this, I realised that it was problem with different ports in localhost, the solution can be found there:http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2014/08/angularjs-consuming-aspnet-web-api.html.

Basically I should change the project URL in properties to match the front-end project's localhost port and add an 'api' suffix to avoid using the same virtual directory by both projects.

Answer (score 0):

@satish,
Global.asax:

```
namespace WebAPI_Training
{
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);            
    }
}
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
 namespace WebAPI_Training
 {
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services         

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
}
```